# How do you assign n buttons to jQuery dialog in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below does something odd.  Whenever you click a button in the dialog, you see "test5" as the alert text, not "test0", "test2", ... "test4" respectively for each button.  Something about assigning the function in a loop is not working.

```
var arrbuttons = [];

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    arrbuttons.push({click: function() { alert('test'+i);}, text:'test'+i});
}

jQuery("#requestdialog").dialog(
    {
        title: "test",
        height: 250,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: arrbuttons
    }
```

Comment: You need to use a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's all about scope and closures :

```
var arrbuttons = [];

for (var j=0; j<5; j++) {
    (function(i) {
        arrbuttons.push({click: function() { alert('test'+i);}, text:'test'+i});
    })(j);
}

jQuery("#requestdialog").dialog(
    {
        title: "test",
        height: 250,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: arrbuttons
    }
```